# NPM and Bun are freezing after updating to MacOS Sonoma

Tags: npm-install, bun

I recently, 10/10/2023, updated my MacOS to Sonoma14. Afterwards, NPM nor Bun wants to install packages for me, they just freeze up. Luckily I can press ctrl+c and stop the process. Theres is an open issue for it on GitHub (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6843), with no fix yet. Curious if anyone else is experiencing the same issue and if they fixed it by themselves. Really need help!

Environment:
M2 Macbook Air
MacOS Sonoma 14.0.0
NodeJS version 20.8.0
NPM version 10.1.0
BunJS version 1.0.4

Things I've tried are uninstall/reinstalling npm, bun and node. Tried a different project to run the commands under. Tried other commands and some kinda work how theyre suppose to. For instance npm init created a package.json folder but not a node_modules folder

Answer (score 1):

deleting node_modules then npm install fixed the issue for me

Comment: I just ended up downgrading my macOS back to Ventura. Is this solution you provided on macOS Sonoma?

Comment: @jamalondon yes the fix worked in macOS Sonoma